# Find out SharePoint custom list items for which metadata is missing SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, metadata

We have a SharePoint 2013 custom list which is holding around 600000 records. Now I want to find out list items for which metadata is not filled.

Answer (score 0):

I have created personal list view in SharePoint with filter conditions like column names [abc] is equal to [empty/Leave blank] AND column name [pqr] is equal to [empty/Leave blank]. 
Similarly I have added other columns as well.